# Define Compound Task in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to define a compound task in sbt so that all tasks that are run in my CI job can be executed in a single commmand.  For example at the moment I am running:

```
clean coverage test scalastyle coverageReport package
```

However I'd like to just run

```
ci
```

Which would effectively be an alias to all of the above tasks.  Furthermore I'd like to define this in a scala file (as opposed to build.sbt) so I can include it in an already existing common scala plugin and thus it becomes availbale to all my projects.

So far (after much reading of the docs) I've managed to get a task that depends just on scalastyle by doing:

```
lazy val ci = inputKey[Unit]("Prints 'Runs All tasks for CI")
ci := {
        val scalastyleResult = (scalastyle in Compile).evaluated
        println("In the CI task")
}
```

however if I attempt to add another task (say the publish task) e.g:

```
ci := {
        val scalastyleResult = (scalastyle in Compile).evaluated
        val publishResult = (publish in Compile).evaluated
        println("In the CI task")
}
```

this fails with:

```
[error] [build.sbt]:52: illegal start of simple expression
[error] [build.sbt]:55: ')' expected but '}' found.
```

My first question is whether this approach is indeed the correct way to define a compound task.

If this is the case, then how can I make the ci task depend on all the tasks mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lazy val ci = inputKey[Unit]("Prints 'Runs All tasks for CI")
ci := {
```

Put a blank space between statements

```
lazy val ci = inputKey[Unit]("Prints 'Runs All tasks for CI")

ci := {
```

---

Also, know that SBT will run your dependent tasks of ci in parallel. Sometimes this is good, but not always, for example in your clean.

There are several ways to run tasks in sequence.

One way:

```
commands += Command.command("ci") {
  "clean" ::
  "coverage" ::
  "test" ::
  "scalastyle" ::
  "coverageReport" ::
  _
}
```

Comment: Yup that works perfectly thank you.  Out of interest how is the syntax for defining that command working?  I.e. it looks like you're applying cons to a number of strings but how are they being transformed into an action and what is the  underscore doing at the end?

Comment: @d80tb7, an underscore is the next (in this case the first and only) parameter in a function. It could be written `{ state => "a" :: "b" :: state }`.